# Error building with leak canary

Tags: memory-leaks, leakcanary

Getting an error with leak canary when doing my gradle sync:

```
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
```

My build:

```
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.assistek.ediary"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 12
}


dependencies {
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang-2.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-net-2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'

}
```

Too old a builde for this library?

Answer (score 1):

Set compileSdkVersion 21. That will make 'android:Theme.Material' available fot your app.